# Can't Add Shortcuts to Home Screen, get Shunted to Folder

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen-folders

I recently started using folders to organize my apps, but I've noticed since then that I can not add any shortcuts to the homescreen. If I try to drop an item on the home screen, it instead gets put into a folder (apparently at random, no less). This happens even if I drop the icon on a completely empty screen with no folders.

If I drag the app out of the folder back to the home screen and drop it, it goes to a different folder instead.

Running Android 2.3.5

Comment: What device and launcher? They vary widely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11004) [reported](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9474) [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10667) which hasn't yet gotten any attention.

A workaround is to use long-press to add items rather than dragging them.